# Queue email notification not working on Dev Sandboxes?

Tags: queue

Is there any limitation on environment where Queue Email Notification are not working?

I created a Queue on Developer Sandbox and set Send Email to Members true, and set Email Deliverability to All Email

[image]

but Email notification are not sent.

I don't understand why Email notification is not working. Doesn't it work since this is Developer Sandbox environment?

Comment: Have you tried looking in the logs in the developer console that the Email Notification is trigger?

Comment: Have you checked that the users email is correct? normally salesforce appends @example.com to the email.

Comment: Yes, user email is correct